# How is this solidity function calling another solidity function without referencing it?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, require, msg.sender

I wanted to create an NFT that chooses between an enum of 3 different NFT types. Also I wanted this choice to be decided at random so the minter doesn't know what type of NFT they'll get. I followed this NFT as a guide https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-mix/blob/main/contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol. The only significant change that I made was switching Chainlink to API3 as my random number provider. I used a basic API3 implementation to get the random number like this https://github.com/Ashar2shahid/eth-denver-hackathon/blob/master/contracts/Requester.sol. I was able to Franken-code the 2 contracts together to get this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@api3/airnode-protocol/contracts/rrp/requesters/RrpRequesterV0.sol";

contract RandomSurfaceReachT1 is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable, RrpRequesterV0 {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    enum Classifier{FIRST, SECOND, THIRD}
    mapping(uint256 => Classifier) public tokenIdToClassifier;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;

    address public airnode;
    bytes32 public endpointId;
    address public sponsorWallet;

    mapping(bytes32 => bool) expectingRequestIdToBeFulfilled;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) requestToRequester;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) requestToName;
    event ReturnedSurfaceReachT1(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 randomNumber);


    constructor(address _airnodeRrp) RrpRequesterV0(_airnodeRrp) ERC721("SURFACE REACHT1 NFT", "SURFACE REACHT1 NFT"){
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function setRequestParameters(
        address _airnode,
        bytes32 _endpointId,
        address _sponsorWallet
    ) external onlyOwner {
        airnode = _airnode;
        endpointId = _endpointId;
        sponsorWallet = _sponsorWallet;
    }

    // QRNG Request Function
    function requestRandomSurfaceReachT1() public returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 requestId = airnodeRrp.makeFullRequest(
            airnode,
            endpointId,
            address(this),
            sponsorWallet,
            address(this),
            this.mintSurfaceReacher.selector,
            ""
        );
        expectingRequestIdToBeFulfilled[requestId] = true;
        requestToRequester[requestId] = msg.sender;
        return requestId;
    }

    // QRNG Fullfill Request
    function mintSurfaceReacher(bytes32 requestId, bytes calldata data) public {
        require(
            expectingRequestIdToBeFulfilled[requestId],
            "Request not awaiting fullfillment"
        );
        expectingRequestIdToBeFulfilled[requestId] = false;
        uint256 newId = tokenCounter;
        uint256 randomNumber = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
        string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[requestId];
        _safeMint(requestToRequester[requestId], newId);
        _setTokenURI(newId, tokenURI);
        Classifier classifier = Classifier(randomNumber % 3);
        tokenIdToClassifier[newId] = classifier;
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        emit ReturnedSurfaceReachT1(requestId, randomNumber);
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

This actually works perfectly. It mints the NFT with a random `Classifier` when you call `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1`. The only problem is that I don't understand how `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1` automatically calls `mintSurfaceReacher`. The first time I called `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1` from hardhat I was shocked when I saw that `mintSurfaceReacher` also ran!

I was thinking that `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1` would just spit out a random number and I would have to design some automated way to feed it into `mintSurfaceReacher` or something, but low and behold `mintSurfaceReacher` ran anyway. So how is `mintSurfaceReacher` running when I call `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1`? I don't see `mintSurfaceReacher` being called in `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mintSurfaceReacher function is called when you invoke requestRandomSurfaceReachT1 function is because the way API3 Airnode is configured to handle the requests.

When request is made to API3 endpoint by calling makeFullRequest function inside requestRandomSurfaceReachT1, mintSurfaceReacher is specified as the target function to be called when the response is received.

This is due to the below line in makeFullRequest function call.

```
this.mintSurfaceReacher.selector
```

This is specifing the function signature of the function to be called when the response is received

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, I didn't notice => `this.mintSurfaceReacher.selector,` in the `airnodeRrp.makeFullRequest()` function call. This obviously where `mintSurfaceReacher` is called.